# Jira Smart Commits. Output Commit Hash to Issue

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket, jira, jira-plugin

I am using **Bitbucket** with mercurial and **JIRA** Cloud .
I want to link **Issues** to **Commits** and vise-versa.

Seeking for integration solutions, all i found was **Smart commits**, but the functionality provided is somewhat limited.

Is there a way to Link the **Commit Hash** to a **Jira issue** and a **Jira issue Key** to a **Commit**?

It would be ideal if the Smart commit supported something like this:

```
JRA-345 #comment {hash}
```

So that way the Commit has a **link** to Issue JRA-345, and on push current commit **hash** would be posted on the Jira issue as comment for example.

Any 3rd party extensions support this??
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect JIRA Software and Bitbucket together as documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/connect-bitbucket-cloud-to-jira-cloud-applications-814190686.html), you should get the linking you desire just by including the JIRA issue key in your commit message.

The commits will visibile in JIRA when view an issue in the 'development panel' on the lower right. This can be expanded to get a more detailed view of the commits linked to the issue.

You can see what the developement panel looks like [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/viewing-the-development-information-for-an-issue-777002795.html#Viewingthedevelopmentinformationforanissue-Makeyourdevelopmentinformationavailablein)

Inside Bitbucket the integration will give you links from issue keys back to JIRA. All references to the JIRA issue key will automatically be converted into links back to the relevant issue.